# Sensei and Woocommerce checkout notices - remove action

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

First question so please be patient!

I'm using Sensei and Woocommerce for an LMS and payment portal site.

When the checkout is complete and a course (from Sensei) has been purchased I want to remove the notice created by Sensei and the top of the page.

It is added with this action.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'Sensei_WC','course_link_from_order' ) );
```

Therefore, how do I remove or change this notice created by the action

I've tried this!

`remove_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'Sensei_WC','course_link_from_order' ) );`

in my functions file by alas, no success!

Thanks in advance

Comment: So I solved this by using the add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', function( $message ) filter and editting my woocommerce - notices - notices.php file